# how to make it in one line after onclick

Tags: node.js, radio-button, bootstrap-4

I have a div in my html:

```
.row(id="div_amount")
  .col-sm-2
    label(for="amount") Amount:
  .col-sm-1
    input(type="text", name="amount")
```

which is perfect as I expected. It displays in one line for both elements.

I have a radio button which have an onclick event for toggle the display of this div section.

```
function div_toggle() {
  div_amount = document.getElementById('div_amount');

  if (radio_value === 0) {
    div_amount.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div_amount.style.display = "none";  
  }
}
```

However, after click on the radio button, it always displays as two lines.

How could I fix it to always display in one line?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to include a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

In `bootstrap4`, `row`s are displayed as `flex`, i.e., "display: flex;". So in your JavaScript if you change it to display as `block`, the columns within the row would be broken.

You can set its display to `flex`, like

```
if (radio_value === 0) {
    div_amount.style.display = "flex";
} else {
    div_amount.style.display = "none";  
}
```

although setting HTML element styles in JavaScript is considered as bad practice IMO.